# how to display leading zeros programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

this field has leading zeros.

newSheet.Cells[i + 2, 5] = drugorder.NDC;

the code is seeing it when it looks up the NDC description in the SQL Server table. But it doesnt display when we write this col to the new sheet in Excel.

how can we display the leading zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the number format of the cells in question to be Text. This will preserve the leading zeroes. Take the `Range` object in question and set its `NumberFormat` property to be `@`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `drugorder.NDC.ToString("0000")` ?